# Script to install EDID on remote PCs not working?

Tags: powershell, deployment, edid

I have a script to apply an EDID configuration for our remote machines. The script works so long as I or someone else is logged in prior to the script running. However, the script fails if the machine sits at the Windows login screen without any active user sessions (ie after a reboot).

I'd like the script to successfully run regardless of active or no active user sessions.

$display = get-wmiobject -class gpu -namespace "root\cimv2\nv"
invoke-wmimethod -path $display.__PATH -name edidport -argumentlist ("\my-srv\Dell u4017.txt","7","3")
invoke-wmimethod -path $display.__PATH -name edidport -argumentlist ("\my-srv\Dell u4017W.txt","7","4")

**The debug log shows:**
Invoke-WmiMethod : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\Windows\Deployadmin\DeployUser\service-1\exec\user.ps1:2 char:24

- invoke-wmimethod -path $display.__PATH -name edidport -argument ...
- ```
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-WmiMethod], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWmiMe
    thod

Any help or recommendations are appreciated. Thank you.